# AngularJS : Isolate the scope of a single directive to avoid updating in other part of application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

sorry for the confused title but I couldn't specify better in short text, I will try to be more explicit in deeply description.

I created a web application with angularJS. One of the requirements was that in a part of the page (in a directive) the page needs to have 3 different DOMs with a number that is going to be updated very often (generally 150 times per seconds each of them).

First solution I adopted was (I show just the directive's controller):

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .controller('myController', function($scope, $interval) {
        $scope.items = [{
            name: 'item 1',
            speed: 100
        },{
            name: 'item 2',
            speed: 150
        },{
            name: 'item 3',
            speed: 300
        }];

        angular.forEach($scope.items, function (item) {
            item.count = 1;
            $interval(function increment () {
                item.count++;
            }, item.speed);
        });
    });
```

and of course in template:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{item.count}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

It works fine, but it creates a problem for the whole page application has several angular directives like ng-show/ng-hide/ng-if/ng-bind/ng-class and others that calls functions and the functions are called a lot of times for the double binding of angularJS.

The reported controller in directive updates often the scope and angular check every time to evaluate the functions related to ng-*. Every single ng-* function is called pretty much 550 times per second.
This scenario is a problem for my application has to run on smartphone too and this solution will consume a lot of battery (for it's execute a lot of useless js functions).

I had as solution to update the number by using pure js and DOM references, but I'd like to keep the whole js code in angularJS.

Can someone please suggest a way to do it in angularJS? Maybe a way to isolate the scope?

Cheers.